# Retrofit login button click not working with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, retrofit

I have tried logging in with retrofit wherein the login button from activity login will redirect me to home activity if successful. Then I tried using fragments. I have two fragments on main activity that can replace each other which are login fragment and register fragment. Know, I know that if I want to use any of the fragment's elements, then I must implement an interface that the mainactivity must implement to be able to use let's say edittext, buttons from fragment. I have done this, but when I try to implement retrofit's asynchronous task in the login button method, when I click it, nothing is happening. I tried putting a toast in the same login button method and it works, but not the retrofit call.

Login fragment:

```
public class LoginLayout extends Fragment {

EditText schoolid;
EditText password;
Login login;
Button loginButton;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_layout, container, false);
    schoolid = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.loginschoolid);
    password = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.loginpassword);
    loginButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.login);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String schoolidtext = schoolid.getText().toString();
            String passwordtext = password.getText().toString();
            login.loginButtonClicked(schoolidtext, passwordtext);
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try{
        login = (Login) activity;
    }catch(Exception e) {

    }
}

public interface Login{

    public void loginButtonClicked(String schoolid, String password);

 }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public void loginUser(String schoolid, String password) {
    //Here we will handle the http request to insert user to mysql db
    //Creating a RestAdapter
    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ROOT_URL) //Setting the Root URL
            .build(); //Finally building the adapter

    //Creating object for our interface
    LoginAPI api = adapter.create(LoginAPI.class);

    api.loginUser(

            //Passing the values
            schoolid,
            password,

            //Creating an anonymous callback
            new Callback<Response>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Response result, Response response) {
                    //On success we will read the server's output using bufferedreader
                    //Creating a bufferedreader object
                    BufferedReader reader = null;

                    //An string to store output from the server
                    String output = "";

                    //Initializing buffered reader
                    try {
                        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result.getBody().in()));

                        //Reading the output in the string
                        output = reader.readLine();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (output.equals("Successful")) {

                        isLoggedIn = true;

                        if(isLoggedIn == true) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }

                        //Displaying the output as a toast
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, output, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    //If any error occured displaying the error as toast
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

    );
}

@Override
public void loginButtonClicked(String schoolid, String password) {
    //this line doesn't work  
    loginUser(schoolid, password);
    //this line works
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: You haven't put the full code of your Activity but I guess you have "implements Login" right? Also, you can remove public from "public void loginButtonClicked..." It's not necessary, nothing to do with the issue though.

Comment: I have implemented the interface. Otherwise, it would have given me an error.

Comment: Do you think its running in the background thread that's why the method doesn't recognize its existence?

Comment: Did you debug it? Is `onAttach` getting called (by the way, you catch any `Exception` without doing nothing, so you will not see any error at that point). Did you put a breakpoint in the `onClick` of the button?

Comment: yes it is being called. If you check the loginButtonClicked method, I have two outputs in there, one is for the retrofit call and the other is a toast to test if the button is really clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragments get attached to activity, the `onFragmentInteraction` is a call back method that your activity use to interact with the fragment

### LoginFragment

**Create a listener**

```
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;


/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p/>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onLoginFragmentInteraction(String schoolidtext, String passwordtext);
}
```

**Initialize the listener**

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) getActivity();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(getActivity().toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

**Call the listener**

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String schoolidtext = schoolid.getText().toString();
        String passwordtext = password.getText().toString();
        //call the listenner on the main activity
        mListener.onLoginFragmentInteraction(schoolidtext, passwordtext);
    }
});
```

### MainActivity

**Implement the call back :**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
                          implements LoginFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

}
```

**Override it**

```
@Override
public void onLoginFragmentInteraction(String schoolidtext, String passwordtext) {
    loginUser(schoolid, password);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a shot.

Comment: Sorry but it's the same thing I did, the login method still doesn't get called whenever I click the button.

Comment: @rendell should I give you a sample?

Comment: In the onLoginFragmentInteraction method, I tested both loginUser() and the toast to see which runs and only the toast ran successfully but not the loginUser().

Comment: so the problem is the function not the button click

Comment: Yes, and I'm really confused because it seems like the login button doesn't recognize that the retrofit function exist.

Comment: I did not, but it works now and I don't even know why. I just place the intent inside the try/catch block in the retrofit method and it worked. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.